# How to set the width of grid elements in pixels?

Tags: grid-layouts

That is all:

How can I set the width of columns in a `Grid` in terms of pixels instead of 'ems'?

To be more precisely, I want to create a grid that is 330 pixels wide, with 3 columns being 110 pixels wide each of them.

This could be a MWE:

```
Panel[Grid[{{"Hello", "World", "!"}}, Spacings -> 1, ItemSize -> All], ImageSize -> {330, 540}]
```

In this example, I tried to force the grid to have a width of 330, but I did not suceeded.

I am also asking for the case where you want each column to have a specific different width (in pixels, again). The previous MWE could serve as MWE for this question (without `ItemSize -> All`, of course).

EDIT: It is not mandatory to use `Grid`. I just thought it was the best way to show my results.

Comment: @Kuba I've just reached a very similar solution by my own, just now. Would you like to post yours as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it was very easy. I found it by myself, and also @Kuba posted it as a comment (I think it has been deleted, though).

I can get what I want by using `Scaled`. It does not directly use pixels, but I can get the same results:

```
Panel[Grid[{{"Hello", "World", "!"}}, 
  Spacings -> 1, 
  ItemSize -> {{Scaled[1/3], Scaled[1/3], Scaled[1/3]}, Automatic}], 
 ImageSize -> {330, 540}]
```